# Why do we start Visitor by calling Acceptor.accept(), and not Visitor.visit()?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In Wikipedia [sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) and in GoF book, usage of Visitor pattern is started by calling `accept` method on some acceptor. But why is it this way? Why can't we start calling `visit` method with desired acceptor as an argument? We can still make visitor behavior depend on 2 types -- of visitor and of acceptor (double dispatch) -- and we can eliminate redundant call (as it seems to me).

Here's sample code to illustrate this:

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visit(AcceptorA acceptor);
    void visit(AcceptorB acceptor);
}

//
// Visitor which sings
// 
class SingingVisitor implements Visitor {
    public void visit(AcceptorA acceptor) {
        System.out.println("sing A");
    }

    public void visit(AcceptorB acceptor) {
        System.out.println("sing B");
    }
}


//
// Visitor which talks
// 
class TalkingVisitor implements Visitor {
    public void visit(AcceptorA acceptor) {
        System.out.println("talk A");
    }

    public void visit(AcceptorB acceptor) {
        System.out.println("talk B");
    }
}

//
// Acceptor subclasses
// 
class AcceptorA implements BaseAcceptor {
}

class AcceptorB implements BaseAcceptor {
}

//
// Launcher class
// 
class VisitorMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Visitor v = new TalkingVisitor();
        AcceptorA a = new AcceptorA();
        AcceptorB b = new AcceptorB();

        v.visit(a);
        v.visit(b);
        v = new SingingVisitor();
        v.visit(a);
        v.visit(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just an example--nobody said it has to be implemented this way.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've asked this question exactly to find out if am I overlooking some advantage of GoF approach or is it just a convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
class House implements HouseAcceptor {
    HouseAcceptor kitchen;
    HouseAcceptor livingRoom;

    void accept(HouseVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
        kitchen.accept(visitor);
        livingRoom.accept(visitor);
    }
}

class Kitchen implements HouseAcceptor {
    void accept(HouseVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class LivingRoom implements HouseAcceptor {
    void accept(HouseVisitor visitor) {
         visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class SpeakingHouseVisitor implements HouseVisitor {
    void visit(HouseAcceptor acceptor) {
        System.out.println("Inside a HouseAcceptor");
    }

    void visit(House acceptor) {
        System.out.println("Inside a House");
    }

    void visit(Kitchen acceptor) {
        System.out.println("Inside a Kitchen");
    }

    void visit(LivingRoom acceptor) {
        System.out.println("Inside a LivingRoom");
    }
}

...
HouseAcceptor acceptor = new House();
HouseVisitor visitor = new SpeakingHouseVisitor();

...
// Doing it your way
visitor.visit(acceptor);
// Output: Inside a HouseAcceptor

// Doing it the right way
acceptor.accept(visitor);
// Output:
// Inside a House
// Inside a Kitchen
// Inside a LivingRoom
```

Note that if you do it your way, the runtime type of your acceptor will not make a difference: the static type will be used. By doing double dispatch you ensure that both runtime types are used.

Answer (score 5):

Using your version, the following will not compile:

```
List<BaseAcceptor> list = ...
for(BaseAcceptor ba: list)
   vi.visit(ba)
```

The java compiler cannot determine (statically) what ba will be, so it cannot decide at compile time which visit method to call. You would need to write an additional method:

```
public void visit(BaseAcceptor ba){
   if(ba instanceof AcceptorA) 
     visit((AcceptorA)ba);
   else if(ba instanceof AcceptorB) 
     visit((AcceptorB)ba);
}
```

This is not necessary using the visitor pattern.

Comment: If I have "stub" `visit(BaseAcceptor)` method in `Visitor` interface, first code *will* compile. But it still won't give me desired behavior, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Visitor`s have no knowledge of how to navigate the private internal fields of a composed `Object`.

If you called `Visitor.visit(something)` then it would have to figure out if that something had private fields which needed transversal.  To do that, you need that `something` to accept your `Visitor`.  Once you decide that navigation must be in the visited objects (and not the `Visitor`), then you realize that you need a call back to the `Visitor` to tell it what the next element in the navigation path is.  Typically that's the `accept(...)` method; however, if you attempted to make `accept(...)` just a wrapper to initiate navigation (by delegation to the parameter), then you need a second set of methods to tell the `Visitor` you're entering X now, your entering Y now.

By using the GOF approach, one can safely subclass an item being visited **and** modify the visiting path to include or skip additional fields.  This would not impact the existing `Visitor`s because their interface would not change.  One wouldn't need to recompile subclasses of the `Visitor` either.

By using your suggested approach, when one added a new type into the hierarchy of to-be-visited items, one would then need to recompile all the visitors, even the visitors had no interest in the new type.

A good compromise would be:

```
public interface Visitable {
  public void accept(Visitor v);
}
```

were all your "data hierarchy" implements Visitable, and your Visitor has a "convenience method" like so

```
public abstract class Visitor {

  public void initiate(Visitable v) {
    v.accept(this);
  }

  public abstract void accept(...);
  public abstract void accept(...);
  public abstract void accept(...);

}
```

But it's up to you if having an interface is preferable to such a base class.  To me I'd favor the more loosely coupled interface, but opinions differ.

Comment: -1 You're describing the Visitor/Composite/Iterator combo. The Visitor pattern is usefull beyond that as well.

And your compromise looks more like a triple-dispatch to me Visitor->Visitable->Visitor.

Comment: @greyfairer, I'm not suggesting triple dispatch.  I'm pointing out that the Visitable must call Visitor multiple times, and if you are intent on putting the "initiation" in the Visitor, it becomes a convenience function which is called once.  I don't like the solution, but I will illustrate it to hopefully point out the code overhead without added benefit.  At least the Visitor->Visitable call only occurs once (but really, why waste the extra stack frame?)

Comment: The Visitor pattern is also useful if you do not have a composite Visitable. In this case the Visitable will call the Visitor only once, but it will call the correct overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

you have no double dispatch. accept usually takes an abstract visitor as an argument.